# Flutter web doesnt work on mobile browsers

Tags: flutter, dart, web, mobile, browser

My project works perfectly in browsers when I open it on the computer, but on mobile devices it just starts loading, and then crashes showing the following screen: [Mobile browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWR8S.png)

"Aw Snap, something wrong while displaying this webpage"

The link that I uploaded the project is this: invite.upbank.digital

My Flutter is on channel stable, 2.0.3, and I already executed the commands for cache repair and clean.

I tried to open it in Safari, Chrome, Edge and Firefox and in all of them the error remains.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you Added Internet Permission in your Android Manifest file?